# How to add a field of a specific BsonType to a MongoDB document using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'd like to add a field and value to a BsonDocument

```
var bsonTypeValue = "Date";
var fieldValue = "2014-04-24T16:42:26";
BsonType bsonType;
const bool IgnoreCase = true;
if (Enum.TryParse(bsonTypeValue, IgnoreCase, out bsonType))
{
    var x = BsonValue.Create(fieldValue);
    doc[fieldName] = x;
}
```

But how do I specify what BsonType x is? x.BsonType is read only.

The above example is hard coded, but what I am trying to do is to have bsonTypeValue and fieldValue come from a config file, so I'd rather not code a large if/else or switch statement if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `BsonTypeMapper.MapToBsonValue()` is what I was looking for. So now my code looks like this:

```
var bsonTypeValue = "DateTime";
var fieldValue = "2014-04-24T16:42:26";
BsonType bsonType;
const bool IgnoreCase = true;
if (Enum.TryParse(bsonTypeValue, IgnoreCase, out bsonType))
{
    var x = BsonTypeMapper.MapToBsonValue(fieldValue, bsonType);
    doc[fieldName] = x;
}
```